# how to make a simple function run with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, function

I've been working with threads lately and kinda just want advice on something. I'll put the function code here just to solve any ambiguity.

```
private void sort() throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException{

    int i;         
    int largest = data.get(0) ;
    int n = fullsize;//data.getsize
    int [ ] tmp = new int [ n ] ;

    for ( i = 1; i < n ; i++)
        if ( largest < data.get(i) )
        largest = data .get(i) ;
    int [ ] count = new int [ largest+1] ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i <= largest; i++)
        count [ i ] = 0 ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        count [ data .get(i) ]++;

    for ( i =0+ 1 ; i <= largest; i++)
    {     
        count [ i ] =count[i]+count[i-1];
        output=  output.concat(Integer.toString(count[i]));
    }

    System.out.print("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getId()+":"+ output+"\n");


    /* for(int b=0; i<count.length;b++)
          System.out.print(count[b]);*/
    for (i=n-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        tmp [count[data.get(i)] -1] = data.get(i);
        count[data.get(i)]--;
    }

    for ( i =0 ; i < n ; i++)
    { 
        data.add(i, tmp[i]);
    }


}
```

This function just basically sorts a linked list in quite a complicated way, I have to use this function though.
That's the function I want to do doing multi threading. But now my question is, how would you go about doing this that each thread does more or less the same amount of work? I was kind of thinking of splitting up the array into parts and then sending each part to be sorted by thread? But I'm not sure if thats the way to do it. Any point in the right direction would be great.

Comment: If you split an array into parts, then sort the parts, you're going to have to merge the results together to get the final result.

Comment: yeah but thats the problem than, il have a bunch or sorted arrays, then il have to sort them again once i merge them

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the array allows for parallel sorting, and it also allows for parallel merging.  For example, consider the following array:

`[3, 2, 6, 4, 9, 7, 12, 1]`

This could be split into segments like so:

`[3, 2, 6, 4], [9, 7, 12, 1]`

From here, both sides can be sorted in parallel.  If these are still too large, they can be split again.  However, this second split can be done in parallel.  This would yield the following:

`[3, 2], [6, 4], [9, 7], [12, 1]`

These can all be sorted in parallel, yielding:

`[2, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9], [1, 12]`

Now we can work backwards, merging in parallel.  One parallel merge step can yield:

`[2, 3, 4, 6], [1, 7, 9, 12]`

From here, there is only one merge step remaining, which cannot be done in parallel:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12]`

The general idea is to split the input until it's of some appropriate size to process directly, and then sort it.  Merging then acts as the opposite of splitting, and like splitting it can be done in parallel.

Java's [Fork/Join Pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) is particularly well-suited for this sort of problem, and there is a [tutorial on its usage here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)